# Different ways of arranging a group of 10 people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can a photographer arrange $8$ people in a row from a family of $10$
people, if

(a) the bride and groom are in the photo. This would be $9! = 9\times8\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1=362880$, correct?

(b) the bride and groom are next to each other in the photo

(c) either the bride or the groom is in the photo, not both

I'm not sure how to start $b$ or $c$. I know $b$ is more restricting than $a$ but I don't know how to represent it

Answer (score 2):

b) Treat the bride and groom as one block. Then we need to choose $6$ out of the remaining $8$ people. Then we can arrange the $7$ blocks as $7!$ but we need to multiply by $2$ since we can have GB or BG.

c) Count the complement. A represents all possibilities and then count when BOTH are in the photo (which is just 6 choose 8). Subtract.

Answer (score 2):

I got a different answer than you did for (a). Since the bride and groom are in the family and in the photo, we have $2$ people chosen already. So we have to select $6$ more people from $8$. So this gives us $\binom{8}{6} * 8! = 1,128,960$. We choose the additional six people for the photo, then we permute the $8$ people in the row.